# A one shot shoujo manga about a girl who's afraid of boys

Tags: kazekou-engekibu

I've been trying to find this particular one shot shoujo manga.

It was about a shy girl with short (red?) hair, who didn't really know how to hang out/deal with boys. An upperclassman who had blond (?) hair from the drama club (?) noticed her predicament. He tried to help her out by going on a date with her to the amusement park. The upperclassman dressed up in different clothing for a stimulation, and he went with the cool ikemen image. They both went on their amusement park date, and the girl gradually fell for the upperclassman. Somewhere along the plot, she thought that she had been cured from her androphobia, but it turns out she was still bad with boys, except for that upperclassman.

The last thing I remember from the manga was that the girl found out she wasn't the only one that the upperclassman was helping. He had other girls ask for make-believe dates, so she felt betrayed, and she probably ran away crying or something. In the end, the upperclassman came to her and said that she was the only one for him, and he promised he would never go on make-believe dates again, all that jazz.

The art was shoujo, similar to [Shiraishi Yuki](https://www.mangaupdates.com/authors.html?id=3742)'s art.

I've been trying to find this manga for the past 4 months, and I don't know if it's real anymore.

If anyone has any idea what manga this is, would you please let me know?

Comment: @Matte, THANK YOU SO MUCH! You've made my day >w< Thank you, thank you so much again!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it perhaps [**Kazekou Engekibu**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=98499) by [Asagi Hikaru](https://www.mangaupdates.com/authors.html?id=14922)?

> Much to her embarrassement, the shy Mashio-chan wins a set of couple
>   tickets for the amusement park. She feels at a loss for what to do
>   since she has always been bad with men. So what will happen to her
>   when the drama club president Katokura Aki suddenly declares that he
>   would erase her awareness...?